# Teams UI Toolkit - Toolbar, Gauge and Map not found in @fluentui/react-teams

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I'm developing a dashboard that will be embed in a Microsoft Teams Tab.

Microsoft provides an UI toolkit: [package](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-ui-component-library) and [figma templates](https://www.figma.com/community/file/916836509871353159) ([source article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/design/design-teams-app-ui-templates#microsoft-teams-ui-kit)). However, I would like to use a Toolbar, Gauge chart and Map chart in my dashboard, but I'm not able to find them in the library [documentation](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-ui-component-library/blob/main/docs/react-teams.echarttypes.md). In figma those components can be found under the Data visualization and Toolbar sections.

Apparently the @fluentui/react-teams package does not implements all the components.
I would be very grateful if someone could tell me where I could find the npm package that implements all the components present in Microsoft Teams UI Kit v3 figma library.

Comment: Please have look into this - https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041051154-Guide-to-libraries-in-Figma
Let us know if you have any query.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, actually I'm looking for the npm package implementing the components provided in the figma Microsoft Teams UI Kit v3 library. Some of the components can be found in @fluentui/react-teams package but not the Toolbar, Gauge chart, Map chart and more. (I rephrase my question to make it clearer)

Comment: You need to create your own component and publish to library.
https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025508373#new-publish